# VSCode extension when clause for extension property

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VSCode extension with a dropdown property and I only want a contribution point when a specific setting is chosen.

Is there any way that I can do something like this?

```
"editor/title": [
            {
                "command": "extension.command",
                "group": "navigation",
                "when": "editorLangId == lua && extension.property == 'foo'"
            }]
```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#check-a-setting-in-a-when-clause Native support is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lex Li in the comments for answering this

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#check-a-setting-in-a-when-clause